# What am I, my little self?

Tags: riddle

> I'm a word - a simple word - you've heard me oft before
>   I am when you place the plates or box upon the floor
>   I'm involved in arson's work and clockmakers' final task
>   I am when authors create a world where players bask
>   I help the surgeon to fix bones and lyricists compose
>   I am when soldiers sharpen blades to fell their fearsome foes
>   I am when you start a journey and when the glue has dried
>   I am all a group or any group with single source implied
>   I am up and down and in and out and off and on again
>   I am key to all the phrases that I do begin
>   I can fill so many holes; so well am I fitted
>   What am I, my little self, unnoticed not omitted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The word

> set

fits here.

> Set things down (plates or boxes, sure)
>  Set a fire, set a clock to the correct time
>  The author's world is the book's setting, or the book is set in the world
>  After you break bone, the doctors set it, and a lyrics are set to music
>  Not sure about the sharpening
>  You set off, glue sets
>  Mathematical set theory
>  You can set up, set down, set in, set out, set off and set on

The other lines are not specific clues.

Comment: set the clock!  :)

Comment: Indeed! I didn't expect a long solve time but I wanted an excuse to share the fact that the word "set" has more definitions than any other English word.

Answer (score 10):

This answer was already given, but I wanted to elaborate some more on how clues can fit.

> Set

I'm a word - a simple word - you've heard me oft before

> Set is the [295th most common English word](http://www.wordfrequency.info/free.asp?s=y)

I am when you place the plates or box upon the floor

> Set the table, set down

I'm involved in arson's work and clockmakers' final task

> Set a fire and set the time when a clock is done

I am when authors create a world where players bask

> Set the scene

I help the surgeon to fix bones and lyricists compose

> Setting bones is important in making sure they heal correctly
> Music can be performed in set, and you can set tempo when writing

I am when soldiers sharpen blades to fell their fearsome foes

> Set the edge of a blade

I am when you start a journey and when the glue has dried

> Set out, set up

I am all a group or any group with single source implied

> [Set(Mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics))

I am up and down and in and out and off and on again

> Up, down, in, out, off, and on can all be preceded with set to make valid phrases.

I am key to all the phrases that I do begin

> All the answers above that start with `set` are defined by how the thing is set.

I can fill so many holes; so well am I fitted

> The word set is able to be a noun, a verb, and an adjective; it works well in most sentences

What am I, my little self, unnoticed not omittied?

Comment: +1 for clarity. My original thoughts had lyricists setting words to music as opposed to the musician composing the tune. Regarding groups, I was thinking more simply of things like a chess set or the complete set of an author's works. Mathematical set is a solution I had not considered.

Comment: I had figured that "I am key to all the phrases that I do begin" was referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_phrase .